# Finding the exact value of cot(23π/4) using Unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find the exact value of $\cot (23π/4)$.

I am thinking that I can find $\tan(23π/4)$ first and then reciprocate it to get $\cot(23π/4)$
I am having trouble trying to represent this on the unit circle.

Is it going to be $\tan (23π/4) = \tan(4π + (7π/4))$.

And I think that the zeroes(tan) are $\{nπ: n $ is an integer$\}$ so $6π$ would be a zero, so from the unit circle, I essentially start like this?

[image]

Comment: The function $\;\tan x\;$ is $\;\pi\,-$ periodic, so you don't need to go all the way to $\;6\pi\;$ , it is enough to take $\;5\pi\;$ ...but even if you did that, remember that $\;\tan x\;$ is an odd function...

Comment: So I am thinking I can instead say 4π + 7π /4. But I'm not sure where to proceed from that

Comment: You seem to be trying to get an *even* multiple of $\;\pi\;$ , as it is usually done when dealing with $\;\cos x\,,\,\,\sin x\;$ , which have a $\;2\pi\;$ period...but here it is enough **any** multiple of $\;\pi\;$, so why not simply $$\frac{23\pi}4=5\pi+\frac{3\pi}4\implies \tan\frac{23\pi}4=\tan\frac{3\pi}4\;...and\;\; etc. ?$$

Comment: The red dot is in the correct place, the tangent at that angle is $y/x$ and the cotangent is $x/y$, using a negative value of $y$ since this point is in the lower half of the plane.

Comment: @DonAntonio If OP is trying to use the unit circle directly rather than relying on derived facts, I think it's reasonable to travel the exact distance around the circle, which puts us in the fourth quadrant as shown, rather than trying to use only the first two quadrants. Of course it would still be useful eventually to learn how to do things more easily using known symmetries of the functions.

Comment: @DavidK He wrote an equation using periodicity of the tangent function, so either in the second of the fourth quadrant it will be exactly the same. With what I'm proposing him he can use correctly periodicity.

Comment: @DonAntonio OP did write a formula that can be interpreted in that way, but from context I still think the argument of the function is written that way in order to represent the shape shown in the figure (two full winds and $7/8$ of a third wind) rather than periodicity of the particular trig function in question. I grant that I am taking the "using unit circle" part very literally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. First, well thought that $\;\cot x=\frac1{\tan x}\;$, then using that the tangent function has a $\;\pi\,-$ period (not $\;2\pi$ !), you get

$$\tan\frac{23\pi}4=\tan\frac{3\pi}4=\frac{\sin\frac{3\pi}4}{\cos\frac{3\pi}4}$$

and now use your knowledge of trigonometry to find the above. The number will be negative , of course (why?)